# save inputs from 2 forms, through one view into 2 tables django

Tags: python, django, database, class, django-views

I am new to django and wanted to know if it is possible to save inputs from 2 forms (displayed on the same html page) into 2 different models through 1 view. Currently, only the first form saves to the table. Form 2 is ignored.

If there is anything missing or incorrect, please explain so I understand what my errors are.

Here is my View:

```
class SubmitChoiceView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'test/test_page1.html'

def get(self, request):
    form1 = SubmitChoiceForm()
    form2 = SubmitMethodForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form1': form1, 'form2': form2})

def post(self, request):
    form1 = SubmitChoiceForm(request.POST)
    form2 = SubmitMethodForm(request.POST)
    if form1.is_valid():
        post = form1.save(commit=False)
        post.user = request.user
        post.save()

    if form2.is_valid():
        post2 = form2.save(commit=False)
        post2.user = request.user
        post.save()
        return redirect('home')

    args = {'form1': form1, 'form2': form2}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Comment: You have `post.save()` in the form2. Copy/paste bug?

Comment: In both the save method calls, you are saving `form1`. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: Thanks I missed that - but it is saving blanks into table2 from form2 now. The ID appears though. Any ideas?